# WPF ShowDialog returns immediately

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008

Sometimes when I call ShowDialog on an OpenFileDialog Window in WPF, the dialog closes immediately with a return value of false.

I'm calling ShowDialog in response to a button click event. I can reproduce this problem using the sample code for OpenFileDialog on MSDN:

```
// Configure open file dialog box
Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension

// Show open file dialog box
Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

// Process open file dialog box results
if (result == true)
{
    // Open document
    string filename = dlg.FileName;
}
```

The problem occurs intermittently when I run my solution in Debug mode from Visual Studio 2008 SP1. It's quite annoying.

Is this a known issue? Are there workarounds?

Comment: For what it's worth, I tried to reproduce this issue and wasn't able to.  I'm using VS 2008 SP1, Win7 64-bit.

Comment: @Ben I'm using Windows XP. @Per It's possible I could have a buggy shell extension... how could I determine whether this is the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the OpenFileDialog needs a Window to attach itself. If no window is present, it returns immediately with "false" as result.

Try someting like this:

```
var ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
ofd.ShowDialog(Application.Current.MainWindow);
```

Greetings
Christian
http://www.wpftutorial.net